# Answering my own question: Shall I give a hint or a full solution?

Tags: discussion, homework

I posted a question half a hour ago. But I think I found the answer myself now.
I understand that answering your own question is appreciated (instead of deleting it).
But I don't know if I should give a hint or a full solution.

It feels a little bit strange to give a hint to my *own* question, I don't know, it is like I'm trying to teach myself :P

On the other hand, if someone is ever searching for this question (and it is a question from a popular book, so I think there is a good chance he/she will find this question), then you could argue that it is better to give a hint instead of a full solution.

Comment: On the contrary, I would expect a user answering her/his own question to give a solution rather more detailed than most.

Answer (score 23):

Generally, hints are given when it seems better that the OP understand how to do the problem rather than being given the answer. Usually, this is when the question is tagged homework, or it seems very likely that the question is from a homework assignment.

In this case, the OP (you) understands the problem, so I see no reason why you should not provide a full answer.

Comment: Another thing, that the OP gains by posting the full answer, is that they might receive some useful comments on their solution from other users.

Answer (score 5):

I think in the long run, we *do* want full answers for all questions.

For homework-type questions, IMHO the ideal procedure is

- Other users provide hints
- The OP, once he has managed to solve the problem, posts a full answer

So yes, please post a full answer.

Comment: I'm glad you said this. I feel like ideally, OP should post their own solution to homework problems, since it serves both the purpose of completion, but also allows other users to give one more round of advice to plug holes if there are any. Copying the answer doesn't give OP anything to learn from besides the literal answer, and also, comments to that answer fixing mistakes might not come until after the question is turned in. Alternatively, if OP posts their own answer, users can help them patch holes in their answer the first time.